# how to set the build output folder in android studio2.1

Tags: build, set, directory

As the title above,I want to set the build output folder like d:/myproject/build/,not as the default path (E:/tests/tests/build/...).
I know I can set the output folder in Project Structure dialog  in Intellj idea ,but in android studio, I can't find that option. Forced by my team leader,
I have to customize the compile output path. So, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have similar question. Android Studio 2.1 (2.1.2) try to generate APK in subproject output folder, not in main project output folder. Where this can be changed?